# Testing async behavior in React with Axios and Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, jestjs, axios

Consider the following oversimplified React component. When you click the button, it makes an API call to an external URL.

- If it is successful, it increments the counter
- If it is unsuccessful, it decrements the counter

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';

class MyCoolButton extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    initialCounter: PropTypes.number.isRequired
  };

  constructor(props) { 
    super(props);

    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      counter: props.initialCounter
    }
  }

  onClick() {
    const url = `/some/url/here`;
    const data = { foo: 'bar' };
    const config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json' } };

    const { counter } = this.state;

    return axios.patch(url, data, config)
      .then((response) => { /* Success! */ this.setState({ counter: counter + 1 }); })
      .catch((error) => { /* Failure :( */ this.setState({ counter: counter - 1 }); });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <span>Counter value is: {this.state.counter}</span>
        <input className="cool-button" type="button" onClick={this.onClick} />
      </div>        
    );
  }

}

export default MyCoolButton;
```

I wanted to write a test case using Jest to ensure that when there is a failure, we are correctly decrementing the button.

I tried the following:

```js
describe('an error occurred while updating', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    axios.patch.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.reject('boo'));
  });

  it('decrements the counter', async() => {
    // NOTE: The below uses Enzyme and Chai expectation helpers

    wrapper = mount(<MyCoolButton initialCounter={99} />);

    // Click the button
    wrapper.find(`.cool-button`).first().simulate('click');

    // Check for decrmented value
    const body = wrapper.find('.container span');
    expect(body).to.have.text('Counter value is: 98');
  });
});
```

The problem is that the click and subsequent `state` update are executed asynchronously, so we check for the failure before it has a chance to even update the component with the failure.

A lot of the examples online seem to suggest `async`/`await` which I don't understand that well. It looks like `await` takes a `Promise` as an argument, but in my case I'm simulating a click which further calls a handler which returns a `Promise`, so I can't `await` on that axios `Promise` to complete directly.

What's the best practice in testing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the following will do the trick:

```
describe('an error occurred while updating', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {});

    it('decrements the counter', async () => {
      const promise = Promise.reject('boo');
      axios.patch.mockImplementationOnce(() => promise);
      const wrapper = mount(
        <MyCoolButton initialCounter={99} />
      );

      // Click the button
      wrapper.find(`.cool-button`).first().simulate('click');
      //do catch().then to make sure test executes after
      //  component caught the rejection.
      return promise.catch(x=>x).then(() => {
        // Check for decrmented value
        const body = wrapper.find('.container span');
        expect(body).to.have.text('Counter value is: 98');
      });
    });
});
```

[Here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async) are some async examples for jest

Comment: Interesting, thanks for that. I'm finding that the `.catch()` in the test actually ends up firing *before* the `.catch()` in the actual react component. So it still ends up testing the DOM before it has a chance to be updated by the component. Is there a good way to make sure the component's promise completes before checking it in the test? Thanks!

Comment: @user2490003 I updated my answer, the test can catch the promise and add a then to make sure tests execute after component catch is finished.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mount the component and simulate the click event before making the assertion:

```js
describe("an error occurred while updating", () => {
  let wrapper;

  beforeEach(() => {
    axios.patch.mockRejectedValue("Mock error message");
    wrapper = mount(<MyCoolButton initialCounter={99} />);
    wrapper.find(".cool-button").simulate("click");
  });

  it("decrements the counter", () => {
    expect(wrapper.find(".container span").text()).toEqual(
      "Counter value is: 98"
    );
  });
});
```